# Python Kivy Zbarcam compiled with Buildozer for Android crash

Tags: python, android, kivy, buildozer

I'm working on an app for Android using Kivy and Zbarcam. I can run it fine on my computer fine and package it fine, but when I put it on my phone, it crashes instantly. I've stripped it back to the bare minimum so I know it's the Zbarcam. Any advice would be greatly appreciated. This is my python file:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from pythonforandroid.recipes.android.src.android.permissions import request_permissions, Permission
import time

request_permissions([
            Permission.CAMERA,
            Permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
            Permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
        ])

demo = """
#:import ZBarCam kivy_garden.zbarcam.ZBarCam
BoxLayout:
    orientation: 'vertical'
    ZBarCam:
        id: zbarcam
        # optional, by default checks all types
        code_types: 'QRCODE', 'EAN13'
    Label:
        size_hint: None, None
        size: self.texture_size[0], 50
        text: ', '.join([str(symbol.data) for symbol in zbarcam.symbols])
"""


class DemoApp(App):

    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_string(demo)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    DemoApp().run()
```

I've tried putting the request permissions part in the build declaration, but I get the same result.

Comment: please be more precise about what you mean by 'crash'. Do you get a stacktrace or at least an error message?

Comment: I get nothing on my phone. The loading screen pops up, then goes away. I've logged a bug report, but I'm struggling to find anything useful in it. It seems to be having a problem getting permission for the camera and storage, but no matter where I stick the android permissions, it won't ask for them.

*** command 'lshal --all --types=all' failed: exit code 136
android.frameworks.cameraservice.service@2.0::ICameraService/default does not exist, or no permission to connect.
*** command 'lshal debug -E android.frameworks.cameraservice.service@2.0::ICameraService/default' failed: exit code 128

Comment: I can not help you with this problem at all unfortunately. But if you believe this is related to permissions, you should edit that into the question title and possibly the tags to get attention from people who know about this. If that does not help, try to ask a new question about the error specifically (most android development is done in Kotlin/java, and the error seems to be coming from that) or ask the question on the kivy-github.